# mDatabase.child(key).addValueEventListener() is not triggering android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I set up an event listener, but after checking several times, I see that it doesn't even trigger in the first place.

```
package com.example.globe_all;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.CharacterIterator;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button signup, login;
    private EditText user_email, password;
    private TextView errortext, forgotpassword, usernameText, passwordText, appearText;
    private String checkPass;
    private int count = 0;
    private ImageView globe;
    private FrameLayout frame;

    private Boolean buttonFlag = false;
    private String accessKey = "";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;

    private SharedPreferences gamePrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor gamePrefsEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

        signup = findViewById(R.id.signup);
        login = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        user_email = findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        errortext = findViewById(R.id.loginerror);
        usernameText = findViewById(R.id.usernametext);
        passwordText = findViewById(R.id.passwordtext);
        forgotpassword = findViewById(R.id.forgotpassword);
        globe = findViewById(R.id.globe);
        frame = findViewById(R.id.frame);
        appearText = findViewById(R.id.appearText);

        loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

        gamePrefs = getSharedPreferences("gamePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        gamePrefsEditor = gamePrefs.edit();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://globall-326315-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
        mDatabase = database.getReference("user");



        globe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (giveBool("first") && giveBool("second")) {
                    Log.d("counter", " " + count);
                    switch (count) {
                        case 0:
                            signup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case 1:
                            login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case 2:
                            usernameText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case 3:
                            password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case 4:
                            user_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case 5:
                            passwordText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case 6:
                            forgotpassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case 7:
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = frame.getLayoutParams();
                            params.height = 300;
                            params.width = 300;
                            frame.setLayoutParams(params);
                            appearText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            gamePrefsEditor.clear();
                            gamePrefsEditor.commit();
                        case 8:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String email_user = user_email.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();

                accessKey = encrypt(email_user) + "&&&" + encrypt(pass);

                Log.d("useruser", " " + mDatabase.child(accessKey));

                buttonFlag = true;

            }
        });
        

        mDatabase.child(accessKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                User u = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                checkPass = u.getPassword();
                Log.d("checkPass", " " + checkPass);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d("snapshot", "Error!");
                throw error.toException();

            }
        });

        if (buttonFlag && checkPass != null) {
            checkPass = decrypt(checkPass);

            String email_user = user_email.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            Log.d("decrypt", " " + checkPass);
            if (pass.equals(checkPass)) {
                errortext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String email = mDatabase.child(accessKey).child("email").toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(LoginScreen.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", encrypt(email_user));
                        loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
                        loginPrefsEditor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent home = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(home);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                errortext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            errortext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signup = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, SignupScreen.class);
                startActivity(signup);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private String decrypt (String toDec) {
        String sh = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String ab = "xytaipckejzsrlfnmhvqgubowd";
        String numshuf = "0123456789";
        String num = "3298561740";

        StringBuilder enc = new StringBuilder();


        CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(toDec);

        while (it.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE)
        {
            char c = it.current();

            if(!Character.isDigit(it.current())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ab.length(); i++) {
                    if (!(ab.charAt(i) == Character.toLowerCase(c)))
                        continue;
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(it.current()))
                        enc.append(sh.charAt(i));
                    else
                        enc.append(Character.toUpperCase(sh.charAt(i)));
                    break;
                }
            } else if (Character.isDigit(it.current())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
                    if (!(num.charAt(i) == c))
                        continue;
                    enc.append(numshuf.charAt(i));
                    break;

                }
            } else if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(it.current()))
                enc.append(it.current());
            it.next();
        }


        return enc.toString();
    }

    public String encrypt (String toEnc) {

        String ab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String sh = "xytaipckejzsrlfnmhvqgubowd";
        String num = "0123456789";
        String numshuf = "3298561740";

        StringBuilder enc = new StringBuilder();


        CharacterIterator it = new StringCharacterIterator(toEnc);

        while (it.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE)
        {
            char c = it.current();

            if(!Character.isDigit(it.current())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ab.length(); i++) {
                    if (!(ab.charAt(i) == Character.toLowerCase(c)))
                        continue;
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(it.current()))
                        enc.append(sh.charAt(i));
                    else
                        enc.append(Character.toUpperCase(sh.charAt(i)));
                    break;
                }
            } else if (Character.isDigit(it.current())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
                    if (!(num.charAt(i) == c))
                        continue;
                    enc.append(numshuf.charAt(i));
                    break;

                }
            } else if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(it.current()))
                enc.append(it.current());
            it.next();
        }


        return enc.toString();
    }

    public boolean giveBool(String s) {
        return gamePrefs.getBoolean(s, false);
    }
}
```

I've updated the code, and pasted in the entirety of the code.

I've taken the `addValueEventListener()` out of my `Onclick()` method, and now I see that onDataChange does indeed trigger, but now I seem to face a problem of an Asynchronious nature, as I am still not getting a `null` out of my data. I am sure that the data I am trying to retrieve exists, so that's not the problem

Comment: The first step is to stop ignoring potential errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its very least that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. --- With that, if neither your `onDataChange` nor your `onCancelled` gets called, you're likely not connected to the database and might want to check your logcat for relevant messages.

Comment: Okay, so I put the throw exception in the OnCancelled, but nothing seems to show up.
Now, I am CERTAIN that I'm connected to the database, as I am able to write to it

Comment: "I am able to write to it" Do you mean that the values from your  app show up in the *Firebase console*? If so and you're using the same `database` variable, that'd indeed indicate the client is connected to the server, but in that case either `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` should always be called. Can you edit your question to show the updated code, and the exact output you get from the `Log` calls?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was happening - seems that when I put my listener in the `onClick()` it wasn't triggering at all, so I took it out of there.
Then, it was always returning `null` so I figured it's about the async, and I went on checking how to fix that problem.
I followed the instructions and created a callback interface that was being used to retrieve the data from the database.
I called the interface in a function:

```
public void readData (MyCallBack myCallBack) {
        mDatabase.child(accessKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String value = snapshot.getValue(User.class).getPassword();
                myCallBack.onCallback(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And the interface:

```
public interface MyCallBack {
    void onCallback(String value);
}
```